# Synthesis error on a CASE statement in Verilog

Tags: verilog, synthesis, case-statement, register-transfer-level, cadence

I m  new in Verilog and I would like to know your opinion about an error I get when trying to synthesize the part of my code cited below:

```
input [31:0] A;
reg [31:0] X,Y;
reg [15:0] width;
input action;       

always@*
begin

  width= A [31:16]; 
  if (action==1)    
  begin    
    case (width) 
      16'b0: X=0;
        default: 
          begin
            for (i=32; i>=width+1 ; i=i-1)
              X[i]=0;
            for (i=width; i>=0; i=i-1)
              X[i]=1;
          end 
    endcase 
    Y=X >> 1;
  end
end
```

I m using Cadence synthesis tool and the error that i get is  in this part of my code saying :

> Index 'X[-1]' is not within the valid range of the declaration [31:0]

which i don't understand because even if `width=0` i have a special case that should not involve the for loop. i also tried increasing the limits to `width +2`,`width +1` and then `shift the quantity X by 2` ..but also got the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how `i` could be -1, but it is possible for it to be greater than 31 which is out of range. There are couple of synthesis issues:

1. `i=32` is already out of range for `X[31:0]`. Its MSB is 31.
2. `i` will go out of range when `width > 31`. `width` is a 16-bit unsigned value, meaning its maximum value is 65535 *(i.e. 2<sup>16</sup>-1)* and its minimum is 0.
3. Synthesis requires loops to static unroll. This means the number of loops must be constant. Variables such as `width` cannot be in the loops condition.

A synthesis-able for loop will look as follows:

```
for (i=31; i>=0; i=i-1)
  X[i] = (width>=i);
```

---

I'm assuming the `width= A [31:16];` above the always block is a copy past typo as it is illegal syntax. I'm also assuming there are no additional assignments on `width`, `X`, `Y`, or `i` outside of the always block. Otherwise there are additional errors.

Comment: I do not think `for (i=width; i>=0; i=i-1)` can be statically unrolled which I would have thought also caused synthesis issues.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution! The first mistake was mine when I was altering the code. I was also thinking the upper limit that should be a problem but the error message was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly why you're hitting the -1 condition, but it looks like you are trying to create a mask of width "width", which would be more easily accomplished as:

```
always @*
  begin
    X = ((1 << width[4:0]) - 1)
  end
```

Edit: Added width specifier to shift, this may reduce synthesis area

Comment: Thank you a lot! I also have thought of that but it synthesized into a "monster" along with the rest of the design.. even worse than  X=2**width-1 .I m just trying to explore the possibilities to optimize my design in terms of area.